# Debugging native iOS apps, on mac machine in the cloud, through local USB

Tags: ios, native, remote-debugging

I would like to prototype some ideas for iOS apps, but I don't have a Mac machine. (also my machine is with AMD processor which makes setupping a vm an issue, I couldn't resolve)

So, my only option (apart from getting a Mac) is to rent a Mac machine in the cloud (macincloud is what I am headed for).

I would like to debug an app (native, not web) running on an iPad, I've connected to my local Win7 machine.

Is there a way to enable/share my USB's to the remote Mac, so that Xcode can detect my device and allow debugging of the app?

Comment: Very doubtful.  The latency would be unbelievable.

Comment: I am sure there will be timing issues, which will be hard to debug this way, but this is not the case for probably well-over 90% of the cases.

Comment: @NikolayTsenkov Check out my answer as it seems like a solid workaround from the MacInTheCloud team.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need a tool to share your USB over the internet. Maybe you could try http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-network-mac/ or http://www.net-usb.com

But you probably need admin rights which you won't get with macincloud. Maybe you could try a different provider like http://xcodeclub.com

Also inn the FAQ of macincloud:

How can I easily test my apps on my own iOS hardware using MacinCloud service?

Although it is not possible to make the remote Mac server aware of your iOS devices that are connected to your local computer, there is a workaround:

We highly recommend developers to utilize the free service provided by TestFlightApp.com, which allow you to easily provision your iOS device for development and distribute your app to iOS devices for testing.

Please visit TestFlightApp.com for more informations. You will need to sign up for a free developer account on their website to utilize the service.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that and researched TestFlightApp. They provide an easy distribution to testers, that's all. No debugging.

And while I knew the guys at MacInCloud said it's impossible, I hoped (and still do) someone will prove them wrong on stackoverflow.

Thanks again.

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks. Maybe the guys at MacInCloud would consider pre-installing this on the machines... After all it will make the service a lot better. I will research further and will share my findings here, once I am able to get some answers.

Comment: I am back with some results. I have contacted the team behind USB Network Gate and asked them about debugging an iOS app running on an local iOS device, connected to a shared USB, read by remote Mac machine. This was their answer:
"The current version of USB Network Gate for Mac unfortunately doesn't support USB devices that have multiple configurations, and iPad and iPhone fall into this category. The good news is that this will be fixed in the upcoming version 3.0, which we expect to release in a month or so."

Comment: Did anyone succeed in using eltima's software along with XCodeclub? I am trying but can't succeed when trying to find the USB host ie my client because while connecting through Teamviewer (the mode of XCodeclub), I can't get the ip of my machine. Even when I supply the IP that I get from sites like whatismyip.com, it can't find my machine itself. Seems no one has succeeded in remote debuggin as in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here from google, this is now possible with a couple different solutions as described on the macincloud site:

https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000007775-test-apps-on-physical-ios-devices-connect-a-device

For true local device debugging, USB Gate is their recommended solution.

Answer (score -2):

It appears based on [this post](https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000007764-connecting-from-ios-devices-iphone-and-ipad-) in MacinCloud's Support Portal that this is now possible by installing an app on your physical iOS device:

> 1. On your iOS device, you will need a Remote Desktop App that allows you to access MacinCloud. We highly recommend a free App made by Microsoft called "RD Client" which you can find in the App Store. Download and install it.
> 2. Run the "RD Client" App on your iPad or iPhone. Press the "+" button at the right upper corner to add a new connection.
> 3. Select "Add PC or Server", and input:
>
> PC Name: [Your Server Name].macincloud.com:6000
>
> This "PC Name" field is used to tell the App which server to connect to. In our case, the server is a Mac server. You will receive your server name together with your server login username and password through email after your purchase. If your server name is "A101," then you should input "A101.macincloud.com:6000" in this field. Notice that there is a ":" right before "6000".
>
> User Name: [Your User Name]]
>
> These two fields are all we need to input in order to initiate the connection. Press the "Save" button at the right upper corner, and you will see a new connection icon is created. Simply press the icon to initiate a connection.
>
> On the next screen, press the "Don't ask me for connections to this computer" switch, and press the "Connect" button at the right upper corner.
>
> Now, the "Credentials" page allows you to review your connection information. Make sure the server information and "User Name" is correct. Type your password on this page. You could also do it after you see the Mac login screen. We do not recommend you save password on this page, so do not turn on the "Store user name and password" switch.
>
> Now, press "Done" at the right upper corner to initiate the connection. If you already typed in your password in the previous screen, you are now connected to the Mac. If not, you should see the Mac login screen and you can type your password to log in.
>
> Make sure to log off your account by using the Apple Icon > Log Out menu item. Simply disconnect or close the app will not log you off your Mac server account.

Comment: Does it add your iOS device as a connected USB device on the RDP host? Seems like it's just a remote desktop client.